# Laravel Can't swap PDO instance while within transaction

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, pdo, jobs

I have a method that needs to connect to a named db PgSql connection.
This is my code:

```
try {
        DB::reconnect('nav');
        DB::connection("nav")->beginTransaction();
        $this->createAccountingData($backInvoice);
        DB::connection("nav")->commit();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        DB::connection("nav")->rollBack();
        throw new GenericException($ex->getMessage());
    }
```

The code run into a laravel job.
For few months it worked succesfully, but now it thrown to me this error "Can't swap PDO instance while within transaction."

I ask your help because for all answers I've found DB:reconnect() solves all problem, but not in my case.

Comment: There's probably a transaction pending on something else on another connection which you need to commit or rollback before opening a transaction on a different connection. If this is a persistent script then you may have had a "leak" somewhere.

Comment: Try to restart your DB, mayby you have a unclosed transaction in the DB itself

Comment: I've restarted the db and it doesn't work, but it worked restarting the queue